# How QGIS Python loop through all tables MS SQL Server?

Tags: qgis, python, sql-server, loop

I've got Python code on QGIS 3.12 that adds a MS SQL Server data layer to the map, but I need to add all of them.

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()

uri.setConnection(r"xx.xxx.xxx.xx\xxx", "xxxx", "xxx", "xxxx", "xxxx")

uri.setDataSource("000001","lcentro", "geom","")

uri.setSrid('31982')

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),"Roads","mssql")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

So I can't figure out how to do it for all the geometry tables.

[image: The Table]

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your code generalizable, you can code as follows:

```
from PyQt4.QtSql import * #for QGIS 3.x use instead PyQt5.QtSql
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("postgres");
db.setUserName("postgres");
db.setPassword("postgres");
db.open();
names=db.tables( QSql.Tables)
print names
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tries, I got it this way.

```
#table array
tabelas = (['quadras','lotes','edif','rdatrech','rdaramal'])

#setting conections to DB
dados = QgsDataSourceUri()
dados.setConnection(r"xxxxxx", "1433", "xxx", "user_xxx", "xxxxxx")

#search shapes on tables
for shape in tabelas:
    dados.setDataSource("your_db",shape, "geom","")
    vector_layer = QgsVectorLayer(dados.uri(),"your_db","mssql")
    #add to map
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vector_layer)
```

Comment: yep looks good.The only thing i would look at doing moving forward is making sure your 'tabelas' array is not hardcoded to those table names, but derived somehow from a predicate/query output. Otherwise your code will only ever work for those 5 tables.